# CSS container query not working with vuejs v-deep

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, container-queries

I can't seem to get container queries to work on a parent component with v-deep on the child component:

```scss
.parent {
   container-type: inline-size;
   container-name: parent;

   @container parent (min-width: 600px) {
      ::v-deep .child {
          background: yellow;
      }
   }
}
```

the weird thing is that the code is working without v-deep on my local but not on the server:

```scss
.parent {
   container-type: inline-size;
   container-name: parent;

   @container parent (min-width: 600px) {
      .child {
          background: yellow;
      }
   }
}
```